# Apex Callout - Need help sending AuthenticationHeader. Request Error. Invalid Login

Tags: apex, api, callout, authentication, login-errors

I am trying to send account record information to an external web service. I have created an Apex Class from WSDL. Right now when I pass the request I am not sending authenticationHeader details. In the TransportSoap class I see   "public SagittaServices.AuthenticationHeader AuthenticationHeader;". How do I send that as well as pass my account record information. Below I have refernced the TransportSoap class as well as the class I am using to send the Account data. Any tips would be greatly appreacited. I'm a newbie to Apex.

This is the TransporterSoap class generated by WSDL.

```
 public class TransporterSoap {
    public String endpoint_x = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/sagittaws/transporter.asmx';
    public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
    public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
    public String clientCertName_x;
    public String clientCert_x;
    public String clientCertPasswd_x;
    public Integer timeout_x;
    public SagittaServices.AuthenticationHeader AuthenticationHeader;
    private String AuthenticationHeader_hns = 'AuthenticationHeader=http://amsservices.com/';
    private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://amsservices.com/', 'SagittaServices'};
```

This is my Apex Callout: Confirm Account - sending clientInsert but not login authentication.

```
public class ConfirmAccount{
public static Boolean AsyncFlag = false;


@Future(callout=true)
public static void confirmAccountName(Set<ID> ids) { 
    try {

        Map<ID, Account> mapAccnt = getAccounts(ids);
        SagittaServices.TransporterSoap port = new SagittaServices.TransporterSoap();
        SagittaServices.Results sResult;
        SagittaServices.AuthenticationHeader login = new SagittaServices.AuthenticationHeader();
        port.inputHttpHeaders_x  = new Map<String, String>();




        for(Account accnt : mapAccnt.values()){
            SagittaServices.clientInsertMap accounts = new SagittaServices.clientInsertMap();

            accounts.Guid            = accnt.id;
            accounts.ClientName      = accnt.Name; 


            sResult = port.clientInsert(accounts);
            System.debug('Success:'+sResult.Success+'SagittaId:'+sResult.SagittaId+'SagittaCode:'+sResult.SagittaCode+'Errors:'); 
        }
        AsyncFlag = true;
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.debug('ERROR: '+ ex);
    }
}

private static Map<Id, Account> getAccounts(Set<ID> ids){
    Map<Id, Account> accounts;
    accounts = new Map<ID, Account>([Select ID, Name from Account where ID in :ids]);
    return accounts;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to provide more details or clarify the question? Thanks.